# How to open a terminal file in TextEdit

Tags: 16.04, command-line, server, text-editor

I use `nano <file_name>` to open/edit files on my remote Digital Ocean server (running Ubuntu 16.04). However it's very hard to edit so is there a way to open these files in TextEdit?

I tried to use the proposed solutions below but they do not work:

`open -a TextEdit <my_file_name>` and `open -a TextEdit` both return this:

```
open: invalid option -- 'a'
Usage: open [OPTIONS] -- command

This utility help you to start a program on a new virtual terminal (VT).

Options:
  -c, --console=NUM   use the given VT number;
  -e, --exec          execute the command, without forking;
  -f, --force         force opening a VT without checking;
  -l, --login         make the command a login shell;
  -u, --user          figure out the owner of the current VT;
  -s, --switch        switch to the new VT;
  -w, --wait          wait for command to complete;
  -v, --verbose       print a message for each action;
  -V, --version       print program version and exit;
  -h, --help          output a brief help message.
```

`open -e <my_file_name>` returns:

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

so I tried an alternate method I found.

I added `alias textedit='open -a TextEdit'` to my `.profile`. After that I tested it with `textedit settings.py` and it returned

```
The program 'textedit' is currently not installed.
You can install it by typing: sudo apt install xview-clients
```

So I installed it - but after I tried `textedit settings.py` again, it returned:

```
XView error: Cannot open connection to window server: :0 (Server package)
```

Any idea?

Comment: I think this covers it quite well: [Open file from remote computer on host computer · unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184965/open-file-from-remote-computer-on-host-computer)

Comment: How is that a duplicate? Looks completely different

Comment: I think running your graphical editor on the remote server is exactly what you want here – try `ssh -X user@host textedit`. *Or* you could do it differently like described in the other answers.